# Associate UIVIew with UIButton in IBAction

Tags: ios, uiview

I have a view controller (in a storyboard) with 6 buttons and 6 subviews. Those subviews are connected to IBOutlets and named like "mySubView1", "mySubView2" etc:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mySubView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mySubView2;
```

I want to animate the alpha value of the subview depending on which button was pressed. All 6 buttons are connected to the same IBAction (below) and each button has a tag (1 to 6).

How do I get the subview property name dynamically? eg, mySubView1 if sender.tag = 1 for example, in the animations block below:

```
- (IBAction)animateSubviews:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                      self.mySubView1.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

}

so what I need is something like : self.mySubView[sender tag].alpha = 1 sort of thing, but I'm stumped, so any advice much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Assigning tags to subviews**

Assign tags to your `UIViews`, for example the view that corresponds to button with tag 1 could have tag 101.

```
- (IBAction)animateSubviews:(id)sender {

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                      UIView *subview = [self.view viewWithTag:((UIButton*)sender).tag + 100]; 
                      subview.alpha = 1;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
}
```

**2) Using dynamic selectors** (which answers your original question)

You can use the method `NSSelectorFromString` which returns a `SEL`.

```
UIView *subview = [self performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"mySubView%d", ((UIButton*)sender).tag])];
```

Comment: Thanks very much, looks like either of those will do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong, noatomatic) NSArray* arrayForSubViews;

if (!self.arrayForSubViews) {
    self.arrayForSubViews = @[ self.mySubView1, self.mySubView2, ... ];
}

//get the second view
self.arrayForSubViews[1];
```

Comment: Nice solution also, much appreciated.